# Tolchain for ASP.NET Core, Typescript and type dependencies, npm, saved to Git

Tags: jquery, typescript, asp.net-core, npm, asp.net-core-2.2

I currently have a Asp.Net Core 2.2 project in Visual Studio, where I want to migrate our js files to Typescript.

I am struggling to add the types for libaries like jQuery and knockout. Of course I could do `declare var $: any;`, but I doubt that is the right way to use typescript?

For npm I had created a `package.json` with dependencies to `del`, `gulp`, `jquery` and `@types/jquery`. The first 3 loaded, the type did not.

[image: types/jquery not installed.]

I have tried to find a viable tutorial, but all the ones I found failed me. Im posting here as a last straw, since I am getting frustrated with typescript and its npm world. Typescript sounds awesome to me, but the configuration is like a nightmare.

I hope someone has this before and can help me!
Its important, that I can put the configuration into git sourcecontrol, so it works on the other dev machines without manual changes there.

I can provide more code, but I think it wont be helpful for this question. If you think I can improve this question in any way, please leave a comment.

Comment: When you say "@types/jquery did not load" what do you mean?

Comment: @SeanVieira It didnt get installed. I added a picture to show how it looks in Visual Studio.

Comment: The next question would be "why did it fail"?  It's definitely on NPM: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/jquery

Comment: Thanks, this helped me a lot. At first I didnt know why it didnt load, but this morning I checked, and I had referenced a version that was newer than the latest version of the type.

Comment: Should I delete this question? Since the problem was basically in front of the screen?

Comment: No harm keeping it around, but we'll probably close it as it was a "simple typographical error".